# JavaEE Wildfly EJB not injected, war-only project

Tags: jakarta-ee, javabeans, war, wildfly, ear

I'm new to JavaEE and I created a "hello world" project, using **Hibernate** as JPA provider, build using **gradle** and deployed to **Wildfly**. I want to use `@Stateless` bean for database-aware class, that will do all operations on DB, and then inject it to all "JAX-RS" classes, that contain REST endpoints.

Database class:

```
@Stateless
public class DatabaseManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public DatabaseManager() {
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        // do some db-stuff
        return "EHLO";
    }
}
```

REST class:

```
@Path("/")
@SessionScoped
public class RestMainEndpoint implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private DatabaseManager databaseManager;

    public RestMainEndpoint() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String helloFromDb() {
        return databaseManager.sayHello();
    }
}
```

**Problem is that `@EJB private DatabaseManager databaseManager;` is always `null`. It never gets injected.**

I know that the REST is working, since all non-db related endpoints are working fine. I also assume that `DatabaseManager` bean is created and initialized, since I can see it on Wildfly admin panel.

[image: Wildfly admin panel screenshoot]

I'm not sure if I'm packaging and deploying it right - **it's all packed to single `war`** and deployed. **Is it necessary for me to use `ear`** or create separate project? I tried, but I was unable to successfully convert it to `ear` project with gradle.

---

edit: in `WEB-INF` directory of my source files I won't have any jars, only web.xml and recently added `beans.xml` (which doesn't seem to have any effect). Is it necessary?

`web.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Desktopeo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>desktopeo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                jersey.config.server.provider.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                edu.desktopeo.server
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>desktopeo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`beans.xml` content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

However, in **output `war` archive** (which is really a zip archive), I have a lot of jars:

My project jars: `Commons-1.0.jar` (few POJO classes)

My lib jars: (libs I added by myself using gradle)

```
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections4-4.0.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
guava-19.0-rc2.jar
```

My Database-related jars:

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
sqljdbc4.jar // JDBC driver for MS SQL
```

Other jars: (probably mostly other dependencies)

```
javaee-api-7.0.jar
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b31.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
genson-1.3.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hk2-api-2.4.0-b31.jar
hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar
hk2-utils-2.4.0-b31.jar
jandex-1.2.2.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.inject-2.4.0-b31.jar
javax.mail-1.5.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jersey-client-2.22.1.jar
jersey-common-2.22.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-2.22.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar
jersey-guava-2.22.1.jar
jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.1.jar
jersey-server-2.22.1.jar
jsoup-1.8.3.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

---

### PROBLEM SOLVED

As **Steve C** wrote in the answer, the problem was related to unnecessary `jar`s in output `war`. I changed scope of few of them to `provided` and it helped (and also made `war` 4 times smaller).

Server side gradle build, for future reference:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

idea {
    module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    provided 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.2.Final'
    provided 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.2.Final'

    // other libs, with regular "compile"
}
```

Comment: Please add a list of all jar files in your application's WEB-INF/lib directory. It should work just fine the way that you have described it.

Comment: @SteveC just edited my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your EJB is not being injected because you have packaged your own copy of a JAX-RS implementation into your web app. This implementation does not know how to inject EJBs.

As this is WildFly 9, you can get rid of all the jersey jars, their dependencies and the complete web.xml.

In your gradle file you need to ensure that the javaee-api-7.0 dependency is given a scope of `provided`. It should not be packaged with your application as the server provides these classes. You also need to completely remove gradle references to:

- activation-1.1.jar
- geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
- java.inject-1.jar
- javax.inject-2.4.0-b31.jar
- javax.mail-1.5.0.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
- xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar

because these classes are all provided by the javaee-api-7.0 dependency.

Finally, add a java source file containing:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}
```

which provides the configuration removed with the web.xml and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you very very much Steve, it helped! I've edited my question to include proper `build.gradle` file, "for future generations" ;)

Comment: What if I want to replace Wildfly's jaxrs subsystem with my own (specifically I want to use Jersey instead of RestEasy)? Using RestEasy I was also able to make this work but if I disable the `jaxrs` subsystem through the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and add `jersey 2.19` along with its `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar` dependency I am unable to make injections work. It is as if the given jaxrs .jar doesn't know how to manage injections... Could I replace it with one that has injection management logic and make it work?

Comment: As far as I know this is not easy to do. What does Jersey give you that RestEasy does not?