# NullPointerException when I try to inject EJB in JAX-RS

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

I have seen all the issues noticed in this forum, but I still don't have any solution for my problem.
I work on a EAR project with Maven, Wildfly and JBoss.
When I try to browse to my resource I have NPE.
This is my JAX activator class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/resource")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application{

}
```

and this is my resource class:

```
@Path("/drivers")
public class DriverResource {

    @Inject DriverCpoServiceLocal driverCpoServiceLocal;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DriverCpo> doFindAllDrivers(){
        return driverCpoServiceLocal.findAll();
    }
}
```

This code works  correctly on my personal computer, but in the work computer I see the NPE.
It is driving me crazy.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [JavaEE Wildfly EJB not injected, war-only project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719589/javaee-wildfly-ejb-not-injected-war-only-project/33719902#33719902) to me

Comment: @stevec I don't know, the excellent answer you gave there would apply to any computer you run the project on, assuming the server it is running on is the same. But this is a "works on my computer" kind of question.

Comment: please post the actual NPE you get, with full stacktrace.